# How to move a Rigidbody forward using Bullet Physics

Tags: physics, movement, bullet-physics, character-controller

I'm currently developing a character controller for my game framework, and I'm utilizing the [Bullet Physics](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3) engine for the physics simulation. In the process of adjusting the velocity, I aim to enable entities to move smoothly within the game environment.

My specific question pertains to whether Bullet provides a built-in function or method to move a Rigidbody directly forward.

Thank you in advance!